# Google Places API not correctly returning results of only permanently closed place

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

I have been trying to work on a project for which I need a list of names and addresses for places that are permanently closed within a given radius. I have been using this but it does not appear to be filtering for just permanently closed places. Business status seems to be the issue perhaps? This should return places permanently closed within 50 KM of a given coordinate.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=YOUR-COORDINATES&radius=50000&permanently_closed=true&business_status=CLOSED_PERMANENTLY&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'business_status' field as explain here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSUHI2W9VVg

> Place Search and Place Details both currently support a field called
> permanently_closed, but it doesn’t distinguish between a business or
> location that is closed permanently or closed temporarily. An
> application that relies on the ability to distinguish between those
> values shouldn’t use it. Due to the potential for confusion, we
> strongly encourage developers to use business_status instead. Since
> existing applications may be using permanently_closed to determine
> whether a place is closed for any reason, the Places API will continue
> returning permanently_closed as is.